# UIAutomation c# timeout issue when UI is frozen

Tags: c#, user-interface, microsoft-ui-automation

I am using `UIAutomation` in `c#` to read content of `TextBlock` of WPF Application. It all works fine.

The issue is that if the application gets frozen (not responding) and i try to read the name value of `AutomationElement`, it takes too long and my application gets stucked from running.

Is there any way to set the time limit for how long can it read the value of `AutomationElement`? So if it fails in reading the value, it should return null, possible? I have try-catch but exception doesn't happen, it simply takes too long